# automatically apply CSS rules to a website?

Tags: html, css, firefox

right now, when I load a webpage, I can change the CSS rules that apply to it by doing `Inspect Element` in Firefox and then using `Inspector` and `Rules` to modify certain rules in a HTML div.

But, is there a way to do this automatically? that is, to have the web browser load the webpage and then **automatically** remove certain CSS rules that I would have instructed it to remove?

Comment: You could write an extension to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only built-in way to accomplish this I know of exists in Chrome, by using [Chrome Local Overrides](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+local+overrides) to replace the page response, or the page's CSS link, with your own, adding your tweaks as desired. But this isn't very easy to do.

An easier method is to use an extension to handle this for you, which will work in any browser:

- You can use [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), which will let you write CSS of your own, which can get automatically injected into any website passing the pattern of your choice
- You can use a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) to accomplish the same thing via JavaScript:

  ```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name         Custom CSS
    // @match        https://some-website.com
    // @grant        none
    // ==/UserScript==

    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
    .hyperlink {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    `; // insert rules as desired
  ```

Comment: thanks, Tampermonkey was able to give me what I needed